# Why does pip need an exclamation point to use in iPython?

Tags: pip, ipython

Just a quick example, typing `pip list` doesn't work but `!pip list` does. Is there some syntax regarding the exclamation point and using modules in the ipython shell?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is actually not specific to `pip`, but really any shell command from the iPython notebook. You'll notice other shell commands also work (from the docs):

```
In[1]: !pwd
/User/home/
```

Change directory:

```
In[1]: !cd /var/etc
```

This is simply shorthand that the good folks at Jupyter have included. See [Shell Assignment](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment) in the docs for more of an explanation.

Comment: What may be confusing the OP is that some magic commands have the same name and purpose as system commands.  `%pwd` can used as `pwd` if `automagic` is enabled, and the behavior is similar to `!pwd`.

Comment: I don't know why they use `cd` as an example, cause it doesn't actually do anything. The shell that runs it terminates immediately after.

Comment: It means run it as a shell command rather than a notebook command. For instance, using a command without ! in the terminal same as using the command with ! in jupyter notebook or google code lab.

Comment: Can someone point to me where in the documentation is this referenced?

Comment: Just googled `jupyter exclamation point` and [this is what I found](https://anaconda.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360023858254-Executing-Terminal-Commands-in-Jupyter-Notebooks#:~:text=In%20Jupyter%20Notebook%20you%20can,you%20are%20trying%20to%20use.) in the doc :)

Answer (score 6):

When Python behaves as a system level command we use this exclamatory mark. Example: !python '/content/test.py'-> to run python file named test.py within a colab notebook

Comment: This has to be a comment rather than answering to the questions.

Answer (score 0):

This allows you to run commands as if you were using a terminal, rather than just executing Python code.