# Python3 : module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

Tags: python, tabula, tabula-py

A `.py` program works but the exact same code, when exposed as API, doesn't work.

The code reads the pdf with Tabula and provides the table content as a output.

I've tried :

```
import tabula
df = tabula.read_pdf("my_pdf")
print(df)
```

and

```
from tabula import wrapper
df = wrapper.read_pdf("my_pdf")
print(df)
```

I've installed tabula-py (not tabula) on AWS EC2 running Ubuntu.

More than read_pdf, I actually want to convert to CSV and give the output. But that doesn't work as well. I get the same no-attribute error i.e. `module 'tabula' has no attribute 'convert_into`.

The .py file and the API file (.py as well) are in the same directory and are accessed with the same user.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

EDIT : I tried to run the same python file from the API as OS command (`os.system("python3 /home/ubuntu/flaskapp/tabler.py")`). But it didn't work as well.

Comment: what does your ```pip freeze``` show?

Comment: The details are here - https://pastebin.com/yGBgr5jM. Note, The same API file has more functionalities to expose. So, you'll find more pip components than tabula.

Comment: I tried to run the same python file from the API as OS command (`os.system("python3 /home/ubuntu/flaskapp/tabler.py")`). But it didn't work as well.

Comment: Have you named one of your scripts `tabula.py`, by any chance?  `import` might pick that up in preference to the installed module.  Or do `import tabula; print(dir(tabula))` to see exactly what names it *is* defining.

Comment: No. None of my file is named as “tabula”.

Comment: according to your pip freeze there is not tabula nor tabula-py. but it cannot be the case since you dont get the error in import statement. are you in a virtualenv?

Comment: Thanks Chathurana. Appreciate your help. It's not a virtual env. The details are here - https://www.datasciencebytes.com/bytes/2015/02/24/running-a-flask-app-on-aws-ec2/  Besides, I can run the standalone py file to run tabula.

Comment: can you ssh and see if the same works in python shell?

Comment: I don't know how to check on Python shell. I'll find out. But the program (not API) works when I ssh and run it from Ubuntu terminal prompt.

Comment: There must have been some mistake in the pastebin link. https://pastebin.com/FwGbNL9H is the right one which shows tabula-py 2.0.4 is installed.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I am having same problem

Comment: Yes. It always worked well on my machine as an installed component (not via API). So, I created a docker container and put it in AWS ECS. The API works well from there.

Answer (score 36):

make sure that you installed tabula-py not just tabula
use

```
!pip install tabula-py
```

and to import it use

```
from tabula.io import read_pdf
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer

Comment: i get this error , if try the above
```----> 1 from tabula.io import read_pdf
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tabula.io'
```

Comment: a reference for syntax `!pip` ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/41510454/12846804

Answer (score 9):

There is actually [an entry in the FAQ](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#i-can-t-run-from-tabula-import-read-pdf) about this issue specifically :

> If you’ve installed `tabula`, it will be conflict the namespace. You should install `tabula-py` after removing `tabula`.

Although using `read_csv()` from `tabula.io` worked, as suggested by other answers, I was also able to use `tabula.read_csv()` after having removed `tabula` and reinstalled `tabula-py` (using `pip install --force-reinstall tabula-py`).

Answer (score 7):

If you accidentally installed tabula before installing tabula-py, they'll conflict in the namespace (even after uninstalling tabula).

Uninstall tabula-py and re-install it. That did the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

There is something off with tabula package. I looked inside and there is no __init__.py. You can do:

```
from tabula.io import read_pdf
```

it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

`from tabula import read_pdf` didn't work for me. I've replaced `tabula.read_pdf()` by `tabula.io.read_pdf()` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working in colab then u have to install it by command

**!pip install -q tabula-py
import tabula**

and for using function like read_pdf and convert_into we have to use
**dfs =  tabula.io.read_pdf(path, stream=True)**

**Note**-**tabula.io** (should be used to access these function in colab)
have a good day and long live Data science community.

Comment: Please check existing answers before posting yours to make sure your answer does not duplicate other answers.  You are providing the same commands as in the most-upvoted answer right now (the `-q` option just disables messages, i.e., it is short-form of `--quiet`).

Comment: @AlexK sir i have provided detail working for colab,more elaborative and the ans is well tried and then posted

Answer (score 0):

use from tabula.io import read_pdf
followed by
#declare the path of your file
file_path = "/path/to/pdf_file/data.pdf"

#Convert your file
df = read_pdf(file_path)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code for ease of reading. There appears to be a widely upvoted answer. Please add an explanation of the added value of your answer!

Answer (score -1):

try

`from tabula import read_pdf`

I had the same problem, and this fixed it.

Answer (score -1):

It is working this way:

```
import tabula # just this here!

#declare the path of your file
file_path = "/path/to/pdf_file/data.pdf"

#Convert your file
df = tabula.io.read_pdf(file_path)
```

Thai is all!