# AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I keep getting

> AttributeError: module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read_pdf'

in Visual Studio Code when I try to run the below code:

```
import tabula 

from tabula.io import read_pdf

tables =tabula.read_pdf (' C:/Users/mothe/OneDrive/Desktop/Sample.pdf ')


print (tables)
```

I did install tabula before installing tabula-py, and I've now uninstalled tabula via `using pip uninstall tabula`, but I still get the same problem. How can I resolve this issue?

I was expecting to not get the Attribute error and for the tables to be printed.

Comment: Why `tabula.io` ? import it with `from tabula import read_pdf`, check the [tabula documentation](https://tabula-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tabula.html)

Comment: I get an import error when i dont use .io 

ImportError: cannot import name 'read_pdf' from 'tabula' (unknown location)

Comment: you hava another file called tabula.py ?

Comment: nope,ive got a tabular.py though

Comment: @ReunionTort What is your python and tabula version? Do you have you have `Java runtime` on your environment?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3 : module 'tabula' has no attribute 'read\_pdf'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377106/python3-module-tabula-has-no-attribute-read-pdf)

Comment: I just tried ,my python version is 3.12.2 and tabula is 1.0.5 ,i keep getting the same problem ,i think i might be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so abit of an update ,I was trying all of this through my windows terminal ,spyder ,visual studio 2019 then vs code ,it didn't work in any of the IDEs mentioned ,i recently just ran it on pycharm and it worked ,I can generate tables using tabula !

[image]

only issue im having now is the missing columns but im sure that shouldn't be too hard to work out

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi ReunionTort, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! you could click '✔' to mark it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See also [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)